# Oracle Sql: How to set a default column value on insert select

Tags: sql, oracle, data-migration

In my Oracle 11 database, I have a sql script for inserting(migrating) data from one table into another, this is a problem I encounter a lot, **for instance**:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (eventname, eventplace, eventdate)
SELECT  name, eventplace, "How to insert time here?"   FROM SourceTable;
```

The SourceTable don't have the eventdate column, and it is **"Not Nullable"** in TargetTable, so I have to insert something there, in this case I just want to just use the current time for all rows. How can I do this?

p.s Not only for dates, This could also be a missing varchar column and I might to set a default value in target database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date fields just use sysdate, for varchar fileds I think you have done right, just add "default value" after select works.

Comment: can i just add a text in select clause? I thought it has to be column names from the table?

Comment: Sure you can. just like `insert into t(name) select 'foo' from dual`

Comment: for instance I try to set 0 for a boolean column and it says "invalid identifier"

Comment: I don't think oracle support boolean as a column type, use char for it, set it to 'y' or 'n' or other values you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (
  eventname, 
 eventplace, 
  eventdate)
 SELECT name, 
        eventplace, 
        SysDate -- <- Current Date and Time
   FROM SourceTable;
```

Comment: (select SysDate From Dual) - why do you recommend subguery when mere SYSDATE works ?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko I would be happy if you can generazlie the solution for other kind of data, maybe not current date but a certain old date, or text

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko has privided a nice example to your. Another way is to setup DEFAULT values for non-nullable columns in target table. Is there sonething what prevents you to do it ?

Comment: It seems,  that the solution is either 'just not inserting' a value and let DEFAULT (DDL) one be inserted (or leave the task for a trigger if default is too complex); or to copy default value logic into the insert

Comment: @Dmitry Nikiforov I dont prefer default values while cretaing DB, I just need to know how to set also varchars in target to a default value

Comment: @Spring You can 1) specify default value using ALTER TABLE command. 2) INSERT data omitting default columns in column list 3) Get rid of default settings using ALTER TABLE after insert. It works only if you want to fill data once. Else, if you want to insert data on regular basis you should use Dmitry Bychenko's advise and specify default values explicitly in SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

modify the table definition like this:

```
create table table_name
(
col1 varchar2(10),
default_date_col date default sysdate
);
```

this way u dont need to include the date column in the insert in case u dont need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you Want date format into varchar2 column use

```
 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

You can play with functions how you like

example

`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2013) || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS'),
  'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS');`